# Access report change control values

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an access report that makes labels for our inventory system. I want to put a QR code on each label that would store it's ID number. I found an activeX control that can make QR codes. The problem is I need to change a property of this control in the report. Is there a way to loop through all records in the report to set the `dataToEncode` property of each QR code?

Comment: What is the ActiveX control? It is probably possible.

Comment: I found it here [link]http://www.barcodetools.com/qrcode/qrcode-activex/introduction.html It is pretty simple to use. It has a `dataToEncode` property and that is what drives the QR code.

Comment: I have also been entertaining the idea of building my BMP QR codes before running the report. Do you think this would be a viable solution?

Comment: Just guessing, but have you tried using a detail event to set data to encode to the name of a field? You could build your codes for each product and save them in an attachment, I suppose. eg `myQR.DataToEncode = Me.myDataToEncode`

Comment: Ah! I see there is a video: http://www.barcodetools.com/faq/barcode-activex/using-barcode-activex-in-ms-access-2010.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the video](http://www.barcodetools.com/faq/barcode-activex/using-barcode-activex-in-ms-access-2010.html), you can just link the relevant field to the control source.

[image]

Comment: I should have know it was something that simple. As always you were a huge help @Remou! Thanks a ton!